# locking axis in viewport navigation

Tags: 3d-view, navigation

While navigating in viewport, how can I lock one of the axis and use MMB to turn my object around it (using Blender v 2.90)? I searched for axis locking, went through the docs, getting starter videos, but can't seem figure it out.

Here is an example:

1. When the Z-Axis looking straight up, dragging MMB left to right rotates the object around Z as expected.
2. I then drag MMB up->down to turn my object 90 degrees. Now the Z is sticking out of the screen, Y is looking straight up and X is looking  left to right
3. At this point dragging MMB left/right pans the scene (i.e. continues to rotate around Z) instead of turning around Y. I.e. the question is, how can I fix Y looking straight up and turn my object around it?

Comment: if you are using external software like paraview ...you should add a link to it. Not everybody know every external software here.

Comment: thanks @Chris, I completely rewrote the question. Hope this doesn't create confusion

Answer (score 0):

You can use G (to move an object) then tap X (to move it just on x axis) or Y(y axis) and ...you guessed it Z to move it on the z-axis.

So Tap G->X to move it on global x-axis.

Tap G->X->X to move it on local x-axis. Analog with x, y.

For rotation is the same, just with R -> X (rotates on global x-axis)

UPDATE:

you can navigate with these numpad keys:

[image]

Comment: Grabbing and moving an object transforms it though, right? I.e. coordinates of the vertices of my mesh will get changed. Instead, I just want to keep the object in place and just look at it from another angle, but dragging MMB left/right when Z axis is perpendicular to the screen just pans the scene rather than turning my object.